# What should i do if i want to pass an Junit xml with more than mentioned elements in junit?

Tags: junit, jenkins-plugins

I want to pass an XML to jenkins ,which will have more than junit available elements, in order to show results.

junit available elements are:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <testcase/>
    </testsuite>
<testsuties>
```

But what if i want to pass:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <testcases>
            <testcase>
                <subtestcase/>
           </testcase>
       </testcases>
    </testsuite>
<testsuties>
```